# react select not changing the when state changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

select is not changing value when the state value changes..

my options

```
const options = [
{ value: '', label: "None" },
{ value: "1", label: "Paid" },
{ value: "0", label: "Unpaid" }
];
```

and my state obj is

```
  const [isPaid, setIsPaid] = useState();
```

my select component

```
 <Select
     displayEmpty
    id="billpaid"
    value={isPaid}
    onChange={e => onIsPaidChange(handleFilter, e)}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem value={option.value} key={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>

     const onIsPaidChange = (handleFilter, e) => {
     const paidValue = e.target.value;
     setIsPaid(paidValue);
     return handleFilter(e);
     }
```

i am trying to change my select value from my link action, but select component is not changing when it state changes

```
     </Link><Link onClick={(e) => setIsPaid('')} className="m-1 badge badge-success">
          Clear bill
        </Link>
```

how would i reset my select from outside of the component..